# setting an auto height to an iframe (trustpilot)

Tags: css

Im trying to get an iframe to "grow" when it gets data. Like making and height: auto and max-height: 400px; so it will not grow more than 400px when it receives data.

[trustpilot with no reviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtBjH.png)

this picture shows the trustpilot widget with the height set as auto. The problem is that i know that when it receives reviews it will stay with that height and it will be to small so people need to scroll a lot to see the reviews.
How i can make that the iframe grows when it receives new reviews?

This is the code for the trustpilot widget

```
.trust-review{
            width: 1544px;
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 100%;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left: 50px;
            padding-right: 50px;
            // height: 500px;
            // height: auto;
            // max-height: 400px;
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            h1{
                font-family: TitilliumWeb-Bold;
                font-size: 23px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-style: italic;
                line-height: 0.57;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: @main-color;
                        
            }

            .trustpilot-widget{
                // height: 400px;
                // height: auto;
                // max-height: 400px;
                // background: #f7f7f7;
                iframe{
                    // height: 400px !important;
                    height: auto !important;
                    max-height: 400px;
                }
            }
        }
```

Its an iframe so its content coming from a third party and i cant set like 400px height because when it has no reviews it will give a huge blank space.
Is it even possible?

The html

```
<div class="trust-review">
<h1>Client Reviews</h1>
<!-- TrustBox widget - Product Reviews -->
<div class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-US" data-template-id="x" data-businessunit-id="y" data-style-height="700px" data-style-width="100%" data-theme="light" data-sku="<?=$sku;?>" data-star-color="#c40b13" data-font-family="Titillium Web" data-no-reviews="show">
  <a href="site.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a>
</div>
<!-- End TrustBox widget -->
</div>
```

this div truspilot-widget will then receive the iframe

The iframe is like this but only appears after the page loads

```
<iframe title="Customer reviews powered by Trustpilot" loading="auto" src="widget.trustpilot.com/trustboxes/..." style="position: relative; height: 700px; width: 100%; border-style: none; display: block; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

im trying to add some id or class to this iframe but i think its not possible because its not on my file

Comment: Did you have any HTML? That would be really helpful in answering your question.

Comment: @Kameron im sorry i forgot , the html is there now

Comment: I am not seeing the iFrame in the HTML.

Comment: @Kameron the iframe is just appears when the page loads because it comes from trustpilot.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what the front-end looks like on your side? I am just confused a bit cause I am use to iframe format being such as `<iframe></iframe>`

Comment: Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/gde1Lc6s/3/ // for the view I have currently, it seems I am missing something. Feel free to add to it to help me better solve the issue.

Comment: @Kameron yes the format is that one.

Comment: already added the iframe in the post